# Best way to blink android camera flashlight

Tags: android, flashlight, blink

What is the best way to blink android camera flashlight at interval.
Requirement: Flash ON 200ms ->OFF 100ms->ON 200ms->OFF100ms->ON 200ms -> OFF 1 SEC -> Repeat

I read many threads. Which is best way not to freeze the UI. 
1. Timer
2. Thread sleep
3. Handler
4. Any other approach ?

Comment: thread sleep will freeze the ui if done on the ui thread, so i would avoid that. handler will work and probably be the easiest to implement

Comment: thx..can u provide some sample code of using handler...i did using thread run...but waiting for easy handler implementation...